# Can't access general settings in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, settings, digital-ocean

I am using WordPress 4.1 on my self hosted website. My server runs on Ubuntu 14.10.
Everything seems OK except the General Settings. When I try to go to general setting from the Dash board the browsers connection resets. 
Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to deactivated all plugins and test it? Maybe it's some conflict.

Comment: In wp-config.php, change the debug to true and see if it shows some error.